# How to use color variable with PaintCode & Xcode

Tags: swift, instance-variables, uicolor, paintcode

I have an Icon drawn via PaintCode. I need to change his color in XCode, programmatically.

On PaintCode, I set a Variable "ChevronColor" to the Stroke Color.

[image]

[image]

For now I have:

```
@IBDesignable

class IconClass: UIView {

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        StyleKit.drawIcon(frame: self.bounds, resizing: .aspectFit)
    }
}
```

But I would like to add kind of this, to be able to set the color of the icon.

```
 @IBInspectable
     var ChevronColor : UIColor {
         didSet (newColor) {
             setNeedsDisplay()
    }
}
```

I don't know how to do.

After exporting the StyleKit file, I excepted to have this method available in the stylekit file, but it's not the case:

```
StyleKit.drawIcon(frame:  self.bounds, resizing: .aspectFit, chevronColor: self.ChevronColor)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> TL/DR

Create an expression that takes `red`, `green`, `blue`, `alpha` (`external parameters` in PaintCode) and generates a color (`makeColor` function in PaintCode). The generated color is then assigned to the `Stroke`, `Fill`, whatever, via that expression.

> PaintCode

[image: PaintCode]

> Custom View

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

@IBDesignable class TreeView: UIView {

    /*
     *
     * Notice - supported range for colors and alpha: 0 to 1.
     * Color 0.808, 0.808, 0.808 = gray (starting color in this example).
     *
    */

    @IBInspectable var redColor: CGFloat = 0.808 {
        didSet {
            setNeedsDisplay()
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var greenColor: CGFloat = 0.808 {
        didSet {
            setNeedsDisplay()
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var blueColor: CGFloat = 0.808 {
        didSet {
            setNeedsDisplay()
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var alphaColor: CGFloat = 1 {
        didSet {
            setNeedsDisplay()
        }
    }

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        StyleKit.drawTreeIcon(frame: rect,
                              resizing: .aspectFit,
                              red: redColor,
                              green: greenColor,
                              blue: blueColor,
                              alpha: alphaColor)
    }
}
```

> Changing color example

```
@IBAction func colorButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    // Get color references.
    let red = CIColor(color: sender.backgroundColor!).red
    let green = CIColor(color: sender.backgroundColor!).green
    let blue = CIColor(color: sender.backgroundColor!).blue
    let alpha = CIColor(color: sender.backgroundColor!).alpha

    // Update the PaintCode generated icon.
    treeView.redColor = red
    treeView.greenColor = green
    treeView.blueColor = blue
    treeView.alpha = alpha
}
```

> Demo

[image: Example]

> Reference

The project can be [cloned from my GitHub repo.](https://github.com/backslash-f/paintcode-tests)

Also take a look at [the PaintCode Expression Language guide.](https://www.paintcodeapp.com/documentation/expressions)

Answer (score 5):

[image]

Just edit color in Colors section access level to `Parameter`.